# How could i make a div with rounded borders and make the fa icons inside it centered?

Tags: html, css, border, centering

So i want a div with rounded borders (to make a circle) and inside that i want my fa icons which would be aligned to the middle.

So basically i want a Circle containing an fa icon in the middle just to make it simple.

```css
.normal-page {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

body .normal-page {
  z-index: 998;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: url(../images/tpbg.jpg) top center no-repeat #141416;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.vote-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.vote-fa {
  color: #ff8800;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.vote-container a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="normal-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-handshake-o fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix `width` and `height` and use `text-align:center` and `line-height` to center it, and to make the rounded border you need to add `border-radius:50%;`

> **note**: `line-height` needs to be equal to `height` to center it vertically

**See working example:**

```css
.normal-page {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

body .normal-page {
  z-index: 998;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: url(../images/tpbg.jpg) top center no-repeat #141416;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.vote-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

i.vote-fa {
  color: #ff8800;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #861515;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  border:1px solid #ff8800;
}

.vote-container a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="normal-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-handshake-o fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. just use flex and it works as charm

```
.fa {
    width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 2px solid #fff;
   border-radius: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

I have also updated your snippet.

```css
.normal-page {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

body .normal-page {
  z-index: 998;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: url(../images/tpbg.jpg) top center no-repeat #141416;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.vote-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.vote-fa {
  color: #ff8800;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.vote-container a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* add these lines */
.fa {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="normal-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-handshake-o fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to set a background-color for the icon element, give it `border-radius: 50%` (to make the corners circular, or rounded), `text-align: center;` so the icons are center aligned.

And finally, give the `:before` psuedo-class a `line-height` equal to the height of the element to align the icons vertically.

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
.vote-fa {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ff8800;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.vote-fa:before {
  line-height: 80px;
}
```

```css
.normal-page {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

body .normal-page {
  z-index: 998;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: url(../images/tpbg.jpg) top center no-repeat #141416;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.vote-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.vote-fa {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ff8800;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.vote-fa:before {
  line-height: 80px;
}

.vote-container a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="normal-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-handshake-o fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your icons with a div tag

Here you can go with this code.

It may helpful to you.

```css
.normal-page {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

body .normal-page {
  z-index: 998;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: url(../images/tpbg.jpg) top center no-repeat #141416;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.vote-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.vote-fa {
  color: #ff8800;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.vote-container a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.vote-container .icons {
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 65px;
 width: 65px;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 line-height: 60px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.vote-container .icons i {
line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="normal-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <div class="icons">
          <i class="fa fa-handshake-o fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
        <div class="icons">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
        <div class="icons">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
        <div class="icons">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers fa-3x vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Font Awesome class "3x" because it doesn't fit always well if it has to work with other code.
Put icons inside a div with rounded corners and set a line-height equal to div height, then you can set font-size here (just put 3em like fa-3x does).

```css
.normal-page {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

body .normal-page {
  z-index: 998;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: url(../images/tpbg.jpg) top center no-repeat #141416;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.vote-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.vote-fa {
  color: #ff8800;
}

.vote-container a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 35px;
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="normal-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <div class="circle"><i class="fa fa-handshake-o vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <div class="circle"><i class="fa fa-superpowers vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <div class="circle"><i class="fa fa-superpowers vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="vote-container">
          <div class="circle"><i class="fa fa-superpowers vote-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu risus vitae metus rhoncus tincidunt eu a lorem.</p><br>
          <a href="#">Click here to vote!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Parthoghsh820/rm7zhLv1/1/

```
 <span>Please refer the above fiddle</span>
```

[https://codepen.io/ParthoGhosh/pen/mwjpgv

```
 <span>and the Codepen for your ref</span>
```